# Add ranking column based on conditions and unique values

Tags: python, pandas

I will like to add ranking column based on 3 conditions: Company Name, Brand, Year.

This is my raw data:

```
  CompanyName        Brand  Year
0           A        Razer  2019
1           A  SteelSeries  2019
2           A     Logitech  2019
3           A        Razer  2018
4           A  SteelSeries  2018
5           B     Logitech  2019
6           B         Asus  2019
7           B         Benq  2018
8           C         Asus  2017
9           C        Razer  2017
```

This is my desired outcome: (May be confusing for you)

```
  CompanyName        Brand  Year  Rank
0           A        Razer  2019     1
1           A  SteelSeries  2019     2
2           A     Logitech  2019     3
3           A        Razer  2018     1
4           A  SteelSeries  2018     2
5           B     Logitech  2019     1
6           B         Asus  2019     2
7           B         Benq  2018     1
8           C         Asus  2017     1
9           C        Razer  2017     2
```

Code I have tried but it only loop unique Brand:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
for i,brands in enumerate(df['Brand'].unique):
     df1.loc[i-1,'Rank'] = i
     df1.loc[i-1, 'Brand']= brands

df = df.merge(df1,on='Brand',how='inner')
```

Comment: please dont share images of the dataframes, share samples

Comment: Sample of what?

Comment: Of the dataset. Just copy paste the first rows of your dataset and of the expected output, it'll be easier for people to help you !

Answer (score 0):

please provide a textual dataframe next time in the following format -

please review [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

```
 CompanyName        Brand  Year
0           A        Razer  2019
1           A  SteelSeries  2019
2           A     Logitech  2019
3           A        Razer  2018
4           A  SteelSeries  2018
5           B     Logitech  2019
6           B         Asus  2019
7           B         Benq  2018
8           C         Asus  2017
9           C        Razer  2017
```

quite simply, you can do a groupby your `CompanyName` and `Year` columns and apply a cumulative count :

```
df['Rank'] = df.groupby(['CompanyName','Year']).cumcount()+1
print(df)
      CompanyName        Brand  Year  Rank
0           A        Razer  2019     1
1           A  SteelSeries  2019     2
2           A     Logitech  2019     3
3           A        Razer  2018     1
4           A  SteelSeries  2018     2
5           B     Logitech  2019     1
6           B         Asus  2019     2
7           B         Benq  2018     1
8           C         Asus  2017     1
9           C        Razer  2017     2
```

Comment: Did not work for me. It goes by unique value in Brand column

Comment: It goes by unique value in Brand column. For example, when they see razer, rank is 1, steelseries, rank is 2 etc.. for the whole row

Comment: hmm, I'm not to sure based on your sample data, can you explain the logic of the rank?

Comment: The rank is prioritize on the brand column. As you can see, 1 company can hold the same type of brand, but they are in different year. CompanyName: A

Comment: I've read your question a few times and I don't understand your logic vs your expected output can you explain why Razer is Rank 1 for 2019/2018 for Company A then Rank 2 for Company C in 2017.